# Protractor Accept a Prompt

Tags: angularjs, selenium, window, protractor, prompt

My AngularJS application uses Keycloak for auth. and it opens a window prompt to ask the user to enter a domain name.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
var domain;
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    domain = window.localStorage['com.example.domain'];
}
if (!domain) {
    domain = window.prompt("Enter your customer domain:\n\nNote: This has to be entered only once.", "example.com");
    if (domain && Modernizr.localstorage) {
        window.localStorage['com.example.domain'] = domain;
    }
}
```

If I run my test with safari, I can close this prompt once, login using Keycloak and every other test runs succesfully. But in chrome this prompt opens everytime running the test.

How can I get Chrome to close this prompt and continue to the login page?

I tried

```
 browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent()).then(function () {
        browser.driver.switchTo().alert().then(function (alert) {
            alert.accept();
        });
    });
```

or

```
 browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent()).then(function () {
        browser.driver.switchTo().alert().then(function (alert) {
            alert.accept();
        });
    });
```

But I still get the unexpected alert error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of protractor you are running but ever since 2.0 the time on browser.waits have changed

*"Due to changes in WebDriverJS, wait without a timeout will now default
to waiting for 0 ms instead of waiting indefinitely."*

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes

you might be able to try it without a .then() as below

```
browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 5000);
browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

also I noticed you mention trying two different things but I believe you made a typo because they are both the same.

> I tried
>
> ```
>  browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent()).then(function () {
>         browser.driver.switchTo().alert().then(function (alert) {
>             alert.accept();
>         });
>     });
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>  browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent()).then(function () {
>         browser.driver.switchTo().alert().then(function (alert) {
>             alert.accept();
>         });
>     });
> ```
>
> But I still get the unexpected alert error

And you mention closing the prompt once in Safari, Is this manually or via the test? If it's via the test, what code are you using to do that

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry that was a typo. I actually solved the problem in another way which involves the alert not being opened, but I'll spare you the details.